# How to find the maximum work that can be extracted by two objects which have variable temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility, heat-engine

How to find the maximum work that can be extracted by two objects which have variable temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ with $T_1 > T_2$?

I've thought that the maximum work obtainable is the one produced by a reversible machine, but since the temperatures are not constant I can't use the efficiency of a Carnot heat engine. 
In any case I can write $\Delta S = 0$ where $S$ is the entropy. So it becomes:

$\Delta S = 0 \Leftrightarrow \Delta S_1 + \Delta S_2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \int\frac{\delta Q_1}{T_1} + \int\frac{\delta Q_2}{T_2} = 0$

Which should allow me to find the heat put into the system ($Q_2$) and the one taken out ($Q_1$)
and so the maximum work.
But both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are variables, plus, I have as unknown the final temperature $T_f$ as well, so I don't how to integrate.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  What is the change in entropy for a body of mass M and heat capacity C whose temperature changes from temperature $T_1$ to temperature $T_f$?

Comment: $M c ln\frac{T_f}{T_i}$ right? Actually I've thought it could be:  $M_1 c_1 ln\frac{T_f}{T_i} + M_2 c_2 ln\frac{T_f}{T_i} = 0$ but in this way I should find $T_f$ but then I don't know how to continue

Comment: If you know Tf, then you know the amounts of heat exchanged by each body with the working fluid.

Comment: I don't know $T_f$ since it's even different from $T_e$ the equilibrium temperature  which I could obtain considering the two objects in contact, but in this case, with $T_e$, I don't have any work extracted. So in my problem $T_f \ne T_e$

Comment: But that is not what happens.  The working fluid goes through many mini Carnot cycles, with tiny amounts of heat being transferred in each cycle.  So the final temperature of the solids is not the same as simply placing the solids in contact and letting them equilibrate spontaneously.

Comment: Yes I know that’s why I’ve written that those temperatures are different, but I don’t have a way to find $T_f$

Comment: The final temperatures approach the same value.

Comment: But once I find $T_f$ such that $\Delta S = 0$ how can I find $Q_1$ and $Q_2$?

Comment: If I have a body of mass M and heat capacity C that I cool from T1 to Tf, how much heat have I removed?

Comment: Oh okay I think I got it, thank you very much for your help